# Slick can't connect to SQL Server Database

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I'm running a Scala-Play back end and i'm trying to get slick 2.1.0 to connect to my microsoft sql server database. However i'm constantly getting "Can't Connect To Database" every-time i load up.
These are my settings i'm running slick 2.1.0

slick-extensions 2.1.0 gives me a "unknown artifact" in my IDE

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache, ws, filters, jdbc, evolutions,
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "2.1.0",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0"
)
```

My Application.conf.

```
db.default {
  driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver"
  url = """jdbc:sqlserver://SKYNET\DEV:40000"""
  username = "XXX"
  password = "XXXXXXXX"
}
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. The JDBC connection url is 100% not the problem because iv'e tested that JDBC string in my IDE to connect.

I think its because i can't get the driver from slick-extensions.

EDIT: Have the resolver in my built.sbt aswell.

EDIT UPDATE: I think after some Github slick reading iv'e progressed the new problem is "Cannot load Driver[Driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] cannot be instantiated.]"
Updated Code:

```
db.default {
  slickdriver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver"
  driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SKYNET\\DEV:40000"
  username = "XXXXX"
  password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: Have you added the Typesafe resolver? http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/extensions.html

Comment: yes iv'e got the resolver in there, sorry should have added it to snippet

Comment: Are the triple-quotes the problem? I don't believe the typesafe configuration files support that. You also need to escape the backslash. Try updating the URL to `"jdbc:sqlserver://SKYNET\\DEV:40000"`.

Comment: Not solved.
"Configuration error[Driver not found: [com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver}]]"
is the error i'm getting in my console when play doesn't compile"

Comment: Solved -  "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.2.1.jre8" added into sbt libraryDependencies. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.2.1.jre8",
```

Added into my libraryDependencies in SBT fixed it.